# Probability of 3x3 cube

Tags: probability

A cube with side length as 3, paint all faces red (initially all white), then cut it into 27 small cubes with side length of 1, randomly pick 1 cube, roll it once and see five faces white, what is the probability that cube has the other face as red?

---

Attempt:

6 cube with 1 red face, 1 cube with 0 red face.

So the answer is 6/7?

Comment: Not quite (although it is a tempting conclusion). Are you familiar with Bayes' theorem?

Comment: yup, my answer seems to good to be true. Should have gone through the Bayes path.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Baye's theorem is the way to go here: let $W$ be the event the chosen cube is all white, let $R$ be the event the chosen cube has $5$ white faces, and let $E$ be the event that when the cube is rolled, five white faces appear. By Baye's theorem,
$$
P(R|E)=\frac{P(E|R)P(R)}{P(E)}=\frac{P(E|R)P(R)}{P(E|R)P(R)+P(E|W)P(W)}
$$
The reason for the denominator is the law of total probability, and the fact that the events $R$ and $W$ cover all possible outcomes in $E$. You should be able to fill in these probabilities.

---

To give this an intuitive angle, given that you see five white faces alone, all possible instances of $5$ white faces are equally likely. Six of these instances come from the cubes with one red side (one per cube), and six of these come from the central white cube. Therefore, the probability is $6/12$, not $6/7$.